# Chromecast Sender App Error Codes

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on a Chromecast application on Android. I can't find any documentation on what the status codes mean.

```
Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, mNamespace, message).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Status result) {
        int code = result.getStatusCode(); //What do these codes mean?
    }
});

Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, mApp_id, false).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
        int code = result.getStatus().getStatusCode(); //What do these codes mean?
    }
});
```

When trying to send a message I'll sometimes get status code `7`. What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means network error, see this java [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html).